# Как проверить на подписку папку в telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

в телеграм бот есть проверка каналов на подписку функцией
[GetChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) 
бот может проверить, подписался ли юзер на нужный канал

так же в телеге можно создавать папки, добавлять туда каналы и делиться ими, пример ссылок: https://t.me/addlist/xxxxxxxxxxx, когда переходишь по такой он предлагает подписаться на все каналы, что в папках

как проверить юзера подписан ли он на все каналы в папке, есть ли какой то запрос?

либо второй вариант, отправить боту ссылку на папку, и он сам должен получить результат, какие там каналы в папке, и уже обычным путем через GetChatMember проверить все каналы. Тогда нужен запрос, как узнать все каналы в папке

прикрепил картинку на всякий случай как выглядит подписка на папку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]